# Which pip is not the pip that is called

Tags: python, pip

When I type `which pip` at the terminal, I find `/usr/bin/pip`.
However, when I then go for `$ pip` I receive

```
bash: /home/<user>/.local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

Where is it configured that it's still looking in `.local`?

Comment: check `~/.bash_profile` to start. You can also `grep pip ~/*`

Comment: `which` doesn't see aliases. type `alias` to see if there's a wrong pip alias

Comment: `type pip` sees aliases **and** functions, **and** cached PATH lookups (aka "hashed" locations, which can be cleared with `hash -r`). As such, it's more complete than just combining `which` with a check of the alias list or a specific shell initialization file.